# Upper limit of git config pack.packSizeLimit?

Tags: windows, git

After I put the config in `1.9.4.msysgit.2`:

```
git config --global pack.packsizelimit 5g
```

I get an error like this:

```
$ git log
fatal: bad numeric config value '5g' for 'pack.packsizelimit' in c:/Users/Danny/.gitconfig: out of range
```

After more test I found that the value cannot exceed 4GB. i.e. '3g', '4095m', '4194303k' are accepted while '4g', '4096m', '4194304k' are rejected.

However the documentation says the default value of pack.packsizelimit is unlimited, and a 4GB limitation just doesn't seem rationale.

Anybody know if there's an upper limit of pack.packsizelimit related to other configs? Or this is a hardcoded upper limit? Or there's something wrong with my git version?

Answer (score 1):

In the git source code:

```
$ git grep -C 2 packsizelimit
```

[snippage]

```
config.c:       if (!strcmp(var, "pack.packsizelimit")) {
config.c-               pack_size_limit_cfg = git_config_ulong(var, value);
```

[and]

```
fast-import.c:  if (!strcmp(k, "pack.packsizelimit")) {
fast-import.c-          max_packsize = git_config_ulong(k, v);
```

So the limit is enforced by `git_config_ulong`; the next question is: should it be?

This instance must be:

```
cache.h:extern unsigned long pack_size_limit_cfg;
```

but this one:

```
fast-import.c:static off_t max_packsize;
```

has type `off_t`, which is generally<sup>1</sup> 64 bits.  What about the pack file format itself?  Here the answer is murkier, but [the Git Book says](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/7_the_packfile.html):

> Version 2 indexes can also handle packfiles larger than 4 Gb.

The items in the pack file itself have variable-length (essentially potentially-infinitely-many bits long).  So those are OK, and as long as the index is version 2, it's OK.

Thus, it appears that if `off_t` is 64 bits and if `cache.h` were modified, it would be OK to allow 64 bits here.  However, such files might not be useable on 32-bit-limited systems.  Alternatively, git could use `int64_t` and `git_config_int64` (this type and this routine already exist in git), although it's not clear to me how much work that would take and how that would interact with the rest of git's internals.

It's also worth noting here that `git_config_ulong` enforces a limit based on the size of `unsigned long` on the system on which git was compiled, so this means *your* system has 32 bit `long` (or at least, has support for a 32-bit long model, under which your git was compiled).

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm not sure what systems, if any, still have a 32-bit `off_t`.  I know Linux first began supporting 64-bit file sizes with `off_t` (32 bit) vs `loff_t` (64 bit), but currently `off_t` is an alias for `__kernel_off_t` which is an alias for `long long` in `arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/posix_types_x32.h`, or an alias for `long` in `include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h`.  Hence it's 64-bit on at least one 32-bit system, and 64-bit on systems with 64-bit `long`s, but could be 32 bits on systems with 32 bit `long`s, if they are not using the `long long` variant.

The various BSDs went straight to 64 bits back in the 1990s.

SunOS / Solaris still had 32-bit `off_t` for quite a while; I'm not sure of the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

Torek's answer is pretty thorough, but the short answer is  ...

If you type `gcc -v` from your git-cmd.bat prompt you will see

```
gcc version 4.4.0 (TDM-1 mingw32)
```

Which means msysgit is being compiled with a 32 bit Mingw Gcc compiler.

Which results in the max value for packfilesize being 2^32 or 4GB the way Git is currently coded.